# Saving data in one view controller and displaying it in another

Tags: ios, core-data, viewcontroller

I am currently developing an app the needs to have an initial setting screen (name, date, amount of deposit, and percentage).  I have created a view controller that will add and then save to core data.  I can also retrieve the information.

What I need next is to be able to pop into another view controller and enter continuing number for the same person.  Whenever i enter data into the second view controller it comes back as an addition as if it were a new person.  I need some help to figure it out as i am still new and learning.

Below is the .h and .m files of the two view controllers.

ForexDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ForexDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *startamountTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *startmonthTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *startpercentTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endmonth1year1TextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endpercentmonth1year1TextField;

@property (strong) NSManagedObject *device;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)calcultae;

@end
```

ForexDetailViewController.m

```
#import "ForexDetailViewController.h"

@interface ForexDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation ForexDetailViewController

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

@synthesize device;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if (self.device) {
        [self.nameTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [self.startamountTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"startamount"]];
        [self.startmonthTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"startmonth"]];
        [self.startpercentTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"startpercent"]];
        [self.endmonth1year1TextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"endmonth1year1"]];
        [self.endpercentmonth1year1TextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"endpercentmonth1year1"]];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (self.device) {
        // Update existing device
        [self.device setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
        [self.device setValue:self.startamountTextField.text forKey:@"startamount"];
        [self.device setValue:self.startmonthTextField.text forKey:@"startmonth"];
        [self.device setValue:self.startpercentTextField.text forKey:@"startpercent"];
        [self.device setValue:self.endmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"startpercent"];
        [self.device setValue:self.endpercentmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"endpercentmonth1year1"];

    } else {
        // Create a new device
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Calculations" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newDevice setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.startamountTextField.text forKey:@"startamount"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.startmonthTextField.text forKey:@"startmonth"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.startpercentTextField.text forKey:@"startpercent"];
    [newDevice setValue:self.endmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"endmonth1year1"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.endpercentmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"endpercentmonth1year1"];
}

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

TimeLineViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TimeLineViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *startamountTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endmonth1year1TextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *endpercentmonth1year1TextField;

@property (strong) NSManagedObject *device;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender;



@end
```

TimeLineViewController.m

```
#import "TimeLineViewController.h"

@interface TimeLineViewController ()

@end

@implementation TimeLineViewController

- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

@synthesize device;

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if (self.device) {

        [self.startamountTextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"startamount"]];
        [self.endmonth1year1TextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"endmonthe1year1"]];
        [self.endpercentmonth1year1TextField setText:[self.device valueForKey:@"endpercentmonth1year1"]];

    }

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (self.device) {
        // Update existing device

        [self.device setValue:self.startamountTextField.text forKey:@"startamount"];
        [self.device setValue:self.endmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"endmonth1year1"];
        [self.device setValue:self.endpercentmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"endpercentmonth1year1"];


    } else {
        // Create a new device
        NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Calculations" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        [newDevice setValue:self.startamountTextField.text forKey:@"startamount"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.endmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"endmonth1year1"];
        [newDevice setValue:self.endpercentmonth1year1TextField.text forKey:@"endpercentmonth1year1"];

    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


@end
```

ForexViewController.m

```
#import "ForexViewController.h"
#import "ForexDetailViewController.h"

@interface ForexViewController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *devices;
@end

@implementation ForexViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
    context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
        return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

// Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Calculations"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [device valueForKey:@"name"]]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"startamount"]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"startmonth"]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[device valueForKey:@"startpercent"]];


return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
   }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

    // Remove device from table view
        [self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

}


#pragma mark - Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdateDevice"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedDevice = [self.devices objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        ForexDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.device = selectedDevice;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Way too much code. Cut it down to maX 20 lines, only what is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code that shows how you show each view?

If you're doing this via Storyboard segue's, you should be setting the `device` property on the view controllers when you're preparing for segue.

Currently, I don't see how `self.device` is getting set for either of these view controllers so each time the view loads, it think's there isn't a device and therefore creates a new record for one.

A quick example with a storyboard segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"changeDeviceSettings"]) {
        SomeViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.device = selectedDeviceGoesHere;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just added the ForexViewController.m file.  Hope this helps

Comment: @Scubadivingfool You added the AppDelegate's code, not the .m file you are referring to.

Comment: Have you checked that `device` is not nil when the new view controller is shown (aka that `selectedDevice` is not nil)?

Comment: I have been able to on the first view controller to add an name so the device in the second view controller should not be nil

Comment: @Scubadivingfool Yes, but have you explicitly checked that those values are not nil while the app is running?  You can do this with `NSLog(@"Device is %@", device);` etc.

Comment: Sorry, getting in a little over my head.  Not sure when to use the NSLOG files

Comment: @Scubadivingfool `NSLog` is just a general logging tool that will output something to the debugging console.  Perhaps you need to read up a bit more on iOS debugging before continuing forward.  I am sure though that your `device` is not being set otherwise the logical `if-then` block wouldn't be creating a new record.